# How to use less memory generating Array permutation?

Tags: ruby

So I need to get all possible permutations of a string.

What I have now is this:

```
def uniq_permutations string
  string.split(//).permutation.map(&:join).uniq
end
```

Ok, now what is my problem: This method works fine for small strings but I want to be able to use it with strings with something like size of 15 or maybe even 20. And with this method it uses a lot of memory (>1gb) and my question is what could I change not to use that much memory?

Is there a better way to generate permutation? Should I persist them at the filesystem and retrieve when I need them (I hope not because this might make my method slow)?

What can I do?

Update:

I actually don't need to save the result anywhere I just need to lookup for each in a table to see if it exists.

Comment: Your example shows you are dealing with permutations, not combinations. Your use of the word is wrong throughout the question.

Comment: @sawa Thanks! I searched for such method but couldn't find. It might do it :)

Comment: I don't think your problem is particular to an algorithm. Have you considered how big the answer will be? If you have a string of length 20, the number of permutation is 20! = 2.4e+18. If each element in the array took one byte, then, the resulting array will take up at least 20*2.4e+18 = 4.9e+19 bytes. No matter how good the algorithm is, it would take up much more than 1GB in RAM just for keeping the answer.

Comment: @sawa Awesome input! I just reduced my method into 1 line

Comment: It would be better if you edit other parts of your question to replace the wrong word combination with permutation.

Comment: So I really have to persist the possibilities (permutations) in a file or database right? Is there some good way to do this? Is there some permutation method in batches?

Comment: Ruby will never be a very good language for memory usage. Don't try to optimize it too much.

Comment: Reading the docks seems if I pass a number it will execute a given block with groups of the number size. So I just have to save that somewhere.

Comment: @sawa As you helped out me you could write an answer about the argument for batch process and tell to save results somewhere and I will accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to reiterate what Sawa said. You do understand the scope? The number of permutations for any `n` elements is `n!`. It's about the most aggressive mathematical progression operation you can get. The results for `n` between 1-20 are:

```
[1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040, 40320, 362880, 3628800, 39916800, 479001600, 
 6227020800, 87178291200, 1307674368000, 20922789888000, 355687428096000,
 6402373705728000, 121645100408832000, 2432902008176640000]
```

Where the last number is approximately 2 quintillion, which is 2 billion billion.

That is 2265820000 gigabytes.

You can save the results to disk all day long - unless you own all the Google datacenters in the world you're going to be pretty much out of luck here :)

Comment: Yeah. What a crap :/ I guess it's impossible to do this

Comment: @IsmaelAbreu - I don't know the full answer, but perhaps there is an algo to *look up* a certain permutation among a big set. So let's say you have the 20! permutations, but you could still take a peek at permutation number N, just like indexing an array. Not sure if that would solve your problem or even if it's possible to do though. You would need to head over to the mathematics SO group and ask there.

Comment: Oh! You are right. I don't need to have them all at a time. Because I really just need to lookup if it's a valid word in a list. I should had provide the context. But how much time it would take to generate the permutation for a 20 sized array? A day or more like a week? :p

Comment: Just nitpicking: Factorial is not at all "the most ag[g]ressive mathematical progression operation you can get". Cf. [Graham's number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham%27s_number) or [Busy beaver function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_beaver).

Comment: @sawa Yeah I figured someone would nitpick it. That's why I said "about the most" :) Thanks for the education

Comment: Just accept this one because it opened my eyes and gave me good tips to still make it possible for some cases. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Your call to [`map(&:join)`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) is what is creating the array in memory, as `map` in effect turns an Enumerator into an array. Depending on what you want to do, you could avoid creating the array with something like this:

```
def each_permutation(string)
  string.split(//).permutation do |permutaion|
    yield permutation.join
  end
end
```

Then use this method like this:

```
each_permutation(my_string) do |s|
  lookup_string(s) #or whatever you need to do for each string here
end
```

This doesn’t check for duplicates (no call to `uniq`), but avoids creating the array. This will still likely take quite a long time for large strings.

However I suspect in your case there is a better way of solving your problem.

> I actually don't need to save the result anywhere I just need to lookup for each in a table to see if it exists.

It looks like you’re looking for possible anagrams of a string in an existing word list. If you take any two anagrams and sort the characters in them, the resulting two strings will be the same. Could you perhaps change your data structures so that you have a hash, with keys being the sorted string and the values being a list of words that are anagrams of that string. Then instead of checking all permutations of a new string against a list, you just need to sort the characters in the string, and use that as the key to look up the list of all strings that are permutations of that string.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, that seems a nice solution. I actually done something similar. Checking for strings with the same number of chars

Comment: I’d upvote multiple times if I could. In particular, the last paragraph is really important and a good observation.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you don't need to generate all elements of the set, but rather only a random or constrained subset.  I have written an algorithm to generate the m-*th* permutation in O(n) time.

First convert the key to a list representation of itself in [the factorial number system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system#Permutations).  Then iteratively pull out the item at each index specified *by* the new list and *of* the old.

```
module Factorial
  def factorial num; (2..num).inject(:*) || 1; end

  def factorial_floor num
    tmp_1 = 0
    1.upto(1.0/0.0) do |counter|
      break [tmp_1, counter - 1] if (tmp_2 = factorial counter) > num
      tmp_1 = tmp_2     #####
    end                # # 
  end                 #   #
end                        # returns [factorial, integer that generates it]
                            # for the factorial closest to without going over num

class Array; include Factorial
  def generate_swap_list key   
    swap_list = []              
    key -= (swap_list << (factorial_floor key)).last[0] while key > 0
    swap_list
  end

  def reduce_swap_list swap_list
    swap_list = swap_list.map   { |x|       x[1]                    }
    ((length - 1).downto 0).map { |element| swap_list.count element }
  end

  def keyed_permute key
    apply_swaps reduce_swap_list generate_swap_list key
  end

  def apply_swaps swap_list
    swap_list.map { |index| delete_at index }
  end
end
```

Now, if you want to randomly sample some permutations, ruby comes with `Array.shuffle!`, but this will let you copy and save permutations or to iterate through the [permutohedral space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutohedron).  Or maybe there's a way to constrain the permutation space for your purposes.

```
constrained_generator_thing do |val|
    Array.new(sample_size) {array_to_permute.keyed_permute val}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am missing the obvious, but why not do

```
['a','a','b'].permutation.to_a.uniq!
```

Comment: Thank you but I just figured that out with @sawa comment and just edited my question. But I'm still with the same problem for bigger arrays